# Postgresql IN error: operator does not exist integer = integer[]

Tags: postgresql

This WHERE ANY query in Nestjs / Express works fine:

```
const sql = 'SELECT * FROM members WHERE '+ integerId + ' = ANY(skill_id_array)';
const membersBySkill = await this.entityManager.query(sql
```

);

This WHERE IN query fails with this post's title error message:

```
const sql = 'SELECT * FROM members WHERE '+ integerId + ' IN (skill_id_array)';
const membersBySkill = await this.entityManager.query(sql);
```

My understanding of SQL is IN and ANY should be almost the same queries with almost the same results.

```
integerId is a var integer such as 2.
skill_id_array in Postgres looks like this: {1,2,5}
```

Why is this error happening?  I'm searching with an integer in a column of integer arrays.

Comment: If I try `' IN (unnest(skill_id_array))' `  I get `error: argument of IN must not return a set`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short: `in()` needs a list of scalars, while `any()` needs an array expression.

Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR)

> expression IN (value [, ...])
>
> The right-hand side is a parenthesized list of scalar expressions.

Example:

```
where integerid in (1, 2, 5)
```

> expression operator ANY (array expression)
>
> The right-hand side is a parenthesized expression, which must yield an array value.

Example:

```
where integerid = any ('{1, 2, 5}');
```

Because

> skill_id_array in Postgres looks like this: {1,2,5}

so when passed to the query the expression is enclosed in single quotes and you can use it with `any()`. If you do the same with `in()` you'll obviously get invalid syntax:

```
where integerid in ('{1, 2, 5}');

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "{1, 2, 5}"
```

or, if your ORM uses automatic casting:

```
where integerid in ('{1, 2, 5}'::int[]);

ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps clarify this common issue.  I looked at lots of docs and advice but clear as mud.    There are examples that do vars with DECLARE ...  TABLE ...  but I found nothing useful except setup like this, which also doesn't work: `IN (SELECT skill_id FROM skill_id_array)`   The docs and online advice make it so hard to learn how to code without hard coding values.  Lots of questions about this online but the responses are brief and cryptic.  I've seen a hint that this may work:  `IN (id1, id2, id5)`  but that requires parsing each array from that column into vars, ugh!